# scikit-rf import errors: numpy and collections

Tags: python-3.x, scikits

On

1. Pop!OS 22.04
2. with anaconda
3. running Spyder from a base environment with `python 3.8.18`
4. using the interpreters from other environments, each with `spyder-kernels 2.4.4` installed

But I cannot successfully import scikit-rf.
In an environment with `python 3.9.16`, `numpy 1.26.4`, `scikit-rf 0.18.1`, when I do `import skrf as rf` I get

```
AttributeError: module 'numpy' has no attribute 'complex'.
```

In an environment with `python 3.12.2`, and the same numpy and scikit-rf versions, I get

```
AttributeError: module 'collections' has no attribute 'Sequence'
```

All I can find that is remotely related is [this](https://www.mail-archive.com/debian-bugs-dist@lists.debian.org/msg1901819.html)
Any ideas as to what is wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was not specifying the conda-forge channel, like the directions say:
`conda install -c conda-forge  scikit-rf`